# Why is my SwiftUI List appending all objects again instead of updating existing objects?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, combine, swiftui-list

I'm reading data from Firestore using `.addSnapshotListener` and parsing it to a custom model `Thought`

For each document in my Firestore collection I append a new `Thought` object to a `@Published var thoughts` and iterate through `thoughts` in a `List`.

```
struct Thought: Identifiable {

    public var id: String?
    public var name: String
    public var thought: String
    public var color: String
}

class Observer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var thoughts = [Thought]()

    init(){

        self.thoughts.removeAll()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("thoughts")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            for document in documents {

                var thoughtModel = Thought(id: "", name: "", thought: "", color: "")

                thoughtModel.name = document.data()["name"] as! String
                thoughtModel.thought = document.data()["thought"] as! String
                thoughtModel.color = document.data()["color"] as! String

                self.thoughts.append(thoughtModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThoughtsView: View {

    @ObservedObject var observer = Observer()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.observer.thoughts, id: \.name) { thought in

                    ThoughtCard(color: thought.color,
                                thought: thought.thought,
                                name: thought.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I make changes or add a document in my Firestore collection all objects are appended to my `List` instead of my `List` just being updated like I expect. In other words, if I have 3 items in my `List`, and I change a value in one of the Firestore documents I end up with 6 items in my `List` consisting of the original 3, and a duplicate of the original 3 (modified).

How do I properly update my `List`?

Comment: There are 3 ways.  1. remove all thoughts inside the closure. 2. Or add them to a set. 3. Or build an update function on Thought that will update from the source. Update when found else insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all objects are appended to my List instead of my List just being updated like I expect.

Your expectation is correct, but ...

> `@ObservedObject var observer = Observer()`

... your observer is created only once and kept outside of `ThoughtsView`, so even if a view is reconstructed on update the observed object is used the same, so ...

> ```
> init(){
>    self.thoughts.removeAll()
> ```

this code is called only once, because it is in constructor, and, actually, useless. However this part

> `self.thoughts.append(thoughtModel)`

... is called on every update, because it is in `.addSnapshotListener`. As a result you see what you see - continuous appending.

**Solution**. From the logic of the code I assume your meant this place of container cleanup

```
   self.thoughts.removeAll()
   for document in documents {
```